# Having two data folder in my postgresql setup- Postgresql

Tags: backup, restore, postgresql-9.4, configuration, centos

I am using centos 6 and installed Postgresql_9.4 using the following commands

```
yum  install postgresql postgresql-contrib postgresql-client pgadmin3
yum install postgresql-server
```

After that i verified my config file or "Show data_directory" command to verify that data folder path. 
Its showing `/var/lib/pgsql/9.4/data` but am also having the another data folder in this location `/var/lib/pgsql/data`.

data path 1 --> `/var/lib/pgsql/9.4/data`

data path 2 --> `/var/lib/pgsql/data`

My question is which is my original data folder ??.
And Also my exact data folder is configured in config file means what is the use of another data folder ?

Answer (score 0):

On a terminal, type

```
systemctl cat 'postgresql*'
```

That will show you where the `PGDATA` environment variable is pointing to when you start the service normally via `systemd`, and all the parameters used for starting and stopping the service.